# JQuery start 2 callbacks after keyup

Tags: jquery, callback, keyboard-events, sequential

I have a problem with my code. In particular I want call sequentially 2 callback after keyup event.

```
$('myDiv').keyup(function(){ 

 function1
 function2

});
```

Is it possible waiting the loading of the first function (in `function1` there are SQL requests, appending lines, etc.) before the start of the next function?

Tanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions, depending on what the functions are doing.

1. `function1` does not contain asynchronous calls/code:
   Just put the statements after each other:

   ```
   function1();
   function2();
   ```
2. `function1` contains asynchronous calls/code (I assume this is your case)
   Then you have to pass `function2` as callback to `function1` and call it when `function1` handles the response:

   ```
   function1(function2);
   ```

   where `function1` is e.g. like:

   ```
   function function1(cb) {
       $.ajax({ // asynchronous call
           //...
           success: function(data) {
               // response handled here
               cb(); // call the callback
           }
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: Tank you so much! I've solved my problem with your second solution.  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Put the second function into the first one's ajax method callback, for example:

```
function first(cb) {
    // request something. Passed in function will execute
    // once the request has completed.
    $("#foo").load('/foo', cb);
}

function second() {
    // do something
}

$('myDiv').keyup(function(){ 
    first(second);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a single threaded it will only evaluate `function2` after `function1` has completed. However if you are doing an AJAX in `function1` this will not be the case (AsynchronousJAX), you would want to get around this by putting the call to `function2` in the response handler of the AJAX call in `function1`.